# Docusign Checkbox Require at least 1

Tags: docusignapi

I have a group of checkboxes. At least 1 of these 4 has to be checked. Is there any way to make that happen?

```
$checkboxTabs[] = array(
                                "anchorYOffset" => "-2",
                                "anchorXOffset" => "-5",
                                "anchorString" => "{bk1}",
                                "selected" => false,
                                "tabLabel" => "bk1"

                            );
        $checkboxTabs[] = array(
                                "anchorYOffset" => "-2",
                                "anchorXOffset" => "-5",
                                "anchorString" => "{bk2}",
                                "selected" => false,
                                "tabLabel" => "bk2"
                            );
        $checkboxTabs[] = array(
                                "anchorYOffset" => "-2",
                                "anchorXOffset" => "-5",
                                "anchorString" => "{bk3}",
                                "selected" => false,
                                "tabLabel" => "bk3"
                            );
        $checkboxTabs[] = array(
                                "anchorYOffset" => "-2",
                                "anchorXOffset" => "-5",
                                "anchorString" => "{bk4}",
                                "selected" => false,
                                "tabLabel" => "bk4"
                            );
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for mandatory checkboxes. The alternative available to you are radio buttons.